# Error: The prefix "security" for element "security:authentication-provider" is not bound

Tags: spring, spring-security, applicationcontext

Here's my application-security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!--
  - Sample namespace-based configuration
  -
  - $Id: applicationContext-security.xml 3019 2008-05-01 17:51:48Z luke_t $
  -->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>
```

```
    <!-- Don't set any role restrictions on login.jsp -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <!-- Restrict access to ALL other pages -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*.html" access="ROLE_ADMIN"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/manager/*.html" access="ROLE_MANAGER"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**.html" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER"  />
    <!-- Set the login page and what to do if login fails -->
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" default-target-url="/user/userdashboard/dashboard.html"  />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
</http>

<!--
Usernames/Passwords are
    rod/koala
    dianne/emu
    scott/wombat
    peter/opal
-->
    **<security:authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>**
</beans:beans>
```

Everything works fine but I get this weird error of "The prefix "security" for element "security:authentication-provider" is not bound." even though I have supplied the closing tag. Anyone having any clue about how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use "security" for all elements, by using the [proper namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">
    ...
</beans>
```

And then use "security:" everywhere, for instance:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</security:global-method-security>
```

Or completly get rid of it:

```
...
<authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
...
```

because you configured the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"`